# SCHTASKS can't administer remote tasks

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, scheduled-task

I am trying to stop and then disable a remote task from a build script. The remote server is Server 2k8. The client running the script is Windows 7. Both machines are joined to the domain.

When I run `schtasks /Change /S remoteServer /TN "theTask"`, I get an error `ERROR: The specified task name "theTask" does not exist in the system.` If I run this command locally, everything works. I've verified that the domain user account I am logged into on my computer has administrator privileges to the remote computer.

If I run `schtasks /Query` on the remote computer, I get a listing of all scheduled tasks. If I run the same command remotely with the `/S` switch, only two legacy tasks (Google update tasks) return.

My initial thought was that this could be a permissions error, but when I try to run `schtasks` using the `/u` switch, I get `ERROR: The request is not supported`, which makes no sense because both the client and server are running the modern version of windows scheduler. I'm very confused.

What do I need to do to allow `schtasks` remote access to ALL the tasks on a server?

Edit: `schtasks` seems to only be returning the list of "v1" style tasks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! Turn off windows firewall or enable the `Remote Scheduled Tasks Management` firewall exception.

That note is buried way down in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx#Remarks

Comment: This did not work for me. Also, this does not explain why some tasks are returned and not others.

Comment: Specially port 135.

Answer (score 0):

This might also happen if the user specified in the Principals-->Principal-->UsedId is different from the one who is trying to execute the task.

Answer (score -1):

Your computer and remote computer might have different windows/schtasks version.
The steps below solve my 'ERROR: The request is not supported' issue.

- Copy schtasks.exe from the remote computer at c:\windows\system32 to your computer
- Run the copied schtasks.exe instead of your local schtasks.

Comment: copying a different version of the scheduled tasks executable wouldn't be considered best practice. This also doesn't answer the questions as to why a remote server fails to return the correct information when queried.